# Disconnected during booking process - flight gone?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I was in the middle of booking a flight on the TAP website (the step after I put in the passenger details) when my Internet was disconnected. I tried reloading the page, but there was an error, so I tried to do the booking process again, but now the flight cannot be found anymore.

The flight's in a week, so it could be that it is fully booked, but what are the chances that my flight has been booked by another person?

I know they are using a central booking system, so I'm wondering if my "reservation" is still out there... Unfortunately the service center doesn't answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't give up hope just yet: it's possible that **your previous session is still holding on to the last seat**. You can't access the previous session anymore, but the hold won't last more than 30-60 minutes, so try again and you might find it again.

Comment: This exact thing happened to me as well, it had locked the last seat for me, for just 10-30 mins or so. It was gone when I looked again but was back the next morning.

Answer (score 7):

Your reservation only becomes valid after the final booking step - anything entered in between would be discarded if you don't finish the payment process. So unfortunately the flight in question seems to be booked out (not surprising given that it's so close to Christmas) and you're out of luck.

Comment: Don't give up hope just yet though: it's possible that your previous session is still holding on to the last seat.  The hold won't last more than 30-60 minutes, so try again and you *might* find it again.

Comment: @jpatokal You are correct, the flight popped up again!